# How can I make a divs and h1 adjust in width but act as block to go on a new line

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs each with a different h element inside. How can I make the h elements adjust in width and not act like a block element? How can I make the enclosing div adjust with the width but act as block element in the sense of each one taking a new line.

```css
    .film-container {
       max-width: 70%
    }
```

```html
    <div class="film-container">
       <a class="film-item" href="/blog-post">
          <div class="film-title">
             <h1 class="film-list-title">Title</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="film-intro">
              <h2>Intro</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="film-completed-date">
              <h3>dd-mm-Y</h3>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by adjust in width?

Comment: currently the h elements and nested div take up 100% of the width of the  `.film-container` div. I would like it's width just to be the width of the characters

Answer (score 0):

1) Just apply `inline-block` display rule.

```
h1, h2, h3 { display: inline-block; }
```

2) They already are doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.film-item >div {
  background-color: cyan;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.film-item h1,
.film-item h2,
.film-item h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="film-container">
   <a class="film-item" href="/blog-post">
      <div class="film-title">
         <h1 class="film-list-title">Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="film-intro">
          <h2>Intro</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="film-completed-date">
          <h3>dd-mm-Y</h3>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```